# Comparator to sort a user defined object with nullsFirst

Tags: java, jsp, collections, comparator

I have following list in vector

```
Class abc{
     String view;
     String viewDesc;
}

Data: 
viewDesc = null
viewDesc = null
viewDesc = Maint
viewDesc = Maint
viewDesc = null
viewDesc = uncategorized
viewDesc = uncategorized
viewDesc = null
viewDesc = null
viewDesc = Maint

I want to sort nullsFirst then alphabetically in reverse order as fallows
viewDesc = null
viewDesc = null
viewDesc = null
viewDesc = null
viewDesc = uncategorized
viewDesc = uncategorized
viewDesc = uncategorized
viewDesc = Maint
viewDesc = Maint
viewDesc = Maint

public class SortbyViewComparator implements Comparator<abc> {

    public int compare(abc object1, abc object2)
    {
        return object1.getViewDesc().compareToIgnoreCase(object2.getViewDesc ());
    }
}
```

I am calling this comparator inside jsp with websphere 9 server. And java 1.8 lambda expressions are giving me error and requesting to install was patch.

So I am going with traditional comparator without lambda expressions.

```
JSP code:
Vector abcList;

SortbyViewComparator comp = new SortbyViewComparator();         
Collections.sort(abcList, Comparator.nullsFirst(comp));
```

This is giving me following error

This static method of interface Comparator can only be accessed as Comparator.nullsFirst

@deadPool
    This solution is working closely. I am at least not getting error.
    Now I am getting in this order. Actually in code if its null then I am attaching null to uncategorized.
    So null is nothing by uncategorized.
    viewDesc = null
    viewDesc = null
    viewDesc = null
    viewDesc = null
    viewDesc = Maint
    viewDesc = Maint
    viewDesc = Maint
    viewDesc = uncategorized
    viewDesc = uncategorized
    viewDesc = uncategorized

And I want output like this. All null and uncategorized first and later Maint,HAP,PPA etc

```
viewDesc = null
viewDesc = null
viewDesc = null
viewDesc = null         
viewDesc = uncategorized
viewDesc = uncategorized
viewDesc = uncategorized
viewDesc = Maint                                                              
viewDesc = Maint
viewDesc = Maint
```

Comment: This method is from java-8 in order to use it, you need install java -8 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsFirst-java.util.Comparator-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on java-7 you can write custom `Comparator` to sort `null` first and then in reverse alphabetical order

```
public class SortbyViewComparator implements Comparator<abc> {

   public int compare(abc object1, abc object2) {

      if (object1.getViewDesc() == null && object2.getViewDesc() == null) {
            return 0;

        } else if (object1.getViewDesc() == null) {
            return -1;

        } else if (object2.getViewDesc() == null) {
            return 1;
        }

        return object1.getViewDesc().compareTo(object2.getViewDesc());
   }
}
```

But in java-8 you can simply use `Comparator` static methods

```
Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(abc::getViewDesc).reversed())
```

Comment: I updated my comments in questions. This solution is working closely.

Comment: Try my update answer, just reversing the compare condition should work for you @Sruthi

Comment: I tried reversing and it gave me about mentioned result.

Comment: I updated after using reversed result in original question

Comment: You are doing something wrong, both conditions will not work in same way please check it carefully @Sruthi

Comment: Your solution is good, but your first test, `object1.getViewDesc() == null && object2.getViewDesc() == null` could be better written as `object1.getViewDesc() == object2.getViewDesc()`, which captures an additional case. You could improve it further by writing `Objects.equals(object1.getViewDesc(), object2.getViewDesc())`, which handles null values properly. There's no reason to limit it to null values.

Comment: And I would remove both uses of `else`.

Answer (score -1):

Use it like

```
Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(abc::getViewDesc));
```

Comment: I tried above solution. But I am getting Error Method references are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above. I am sure its due to jdk version not code issue. I am using Websphere 9.0.0.6 JDK which is jdk 1.8.

Comment: If your version of Websphere uses JDK 1.8, it's probably your source level that could be updated.